# Shows lines in contactforms 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to have a clear input field in contactform. Now i have a line in Chrome and safari around my input fields and not at the same place.

Can someone help me with this problem.

https://kasteeldaertrycke.be/reserveer/

Answer (score 0):

Your theme has some kind of custom css included. Perhaps it's the Redux framework?

Anyway it's got this:

```
.wpcf7 input[type=text], .wpcf7 input[type=email], .wpcf7 textarea {
    border-top: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Which is making a white border around the top and bottom, so essentially hiding your box.

If you add this to your theme customizer, it will overwrite the theme's css.

```
body input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required {
    border: 2px solid #767676;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]